# FastAPI: raising exception doesn't return error details as expected in NextJS frontend

Tags: next.js, fastapi

I am using Fastapi as my backend and React(Nextjs) as my frontend. When my frontend makes a post request to my Fastapi backend and fails it does not return the error details.

My Fastapi backend:

```
@router.post("/register")
async def create_user(
    user: _schemas.UserCreate, db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(get_db)
):
   
    
    user = await _services.get_user(user.email, db)
    
    if user:
        raise _fastapi.HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email already in use")

    .....
    ......
    //process token etc
    ......


    return return dict(login_token=token, token_type="bearer")
```

My React (NextJS) frontend:

```
const response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:8000/users/register",
     
    );
    const data = await response.json();

    console.log("data", data);
    console.log("response",response);
```

When I enter a valid email, I get back the correct JSON response as data.
However when I deliberately enter a duplicate email, it doesn't return anything back and in my browser console I get

```
VM366:2 
                
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)
POST http://localhost:8000/users/register 400 (Bad Request)
```

and nothing gets returned as response or data

My Fastapi backend just return:

```
 "POST /users/register HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: return return dict(login_token=token, token_type="bearer")   you passing 2 `return` and add `CORSORIGIN` in fastapi, and your current nextjs code fetching GET method but yours is POST

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite confused.

Nevertheless, I can spot an error in your code:

```
const response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:8000/users/register",
     
    );
    const data = await response.json();

    console.log("data", data);
    console.log("response",response);
```

This piece of code performs a `GET` request to your `POST` endpoint. These are two different `HTTP methods`. While `GET` does not have body data, `POST` does and the endpoint expects thus to have `JSON` data in there. Instead, no data is given and thus the parsing error